# LaTeX - moderncv - spacing problem, overlap of letters

Tags: latex, overlapping

I have some trouble with the spacing of moderncv. Here is an exmaple of the current code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry} % Reduce document margins

\firstname{Ann-Kathrin} % Your first name
\familyname{Lipman-Schindler} % Your last name


\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

\vspace{-1cm}
\section{About}
\cvitem{Name}{Ann-Kathrin Lipman-Schindler}
\cvitem{Date of Birth}{May 28, 1900 in Washington, DC}
\cvitem{CurrentAdresses123}{Fair Parkway 1998, Washington, DC 90394, United States}
\cvitem{Nationality}{US}
\cvitem{e-mail adress}{xyz.xyz@xgy.com}
\cvitem{Telephon}{+0 982 3996 69}
\end{document}
```

The problem ist that the left side "CurrentAdresses123" overlaps the right argument. But why? I used my script so many times and doesn't change something. And now I have the trouble of overlapping letters. Normally, the blue bar will be longer and also the right side will be longer and no overlapping will occur. But what happens now? Please take a look on the image. Thanks in advance

[image: Problem of overlapping letters]

Comment: Related: [No "word break", change the length of cvitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/397183/5764)

Answer (score 5):

You can add something like

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{1.5in}
```

to the preamble of your document. This will increase the space available for for the fist arguments of `\cvitem`.